# Cannot access wp-admin/network/settings.php because of strange redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a local Wordpress multisite install routed on a .dev domain on which I cannot access anything related to the multisite.

The error I get is written below:

```
http://domain.dev/wp-admin/network/settings.php
```

Is not accessible, because it redirects to (look at after .dev):

```
http://domain.devwp-admin/network/settings.php
```

My .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

I have had this error before, but switched to separate WP installs because I could not fix it.

EDIT: below the part of my wp-config.php file for the multisite:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.dev');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');
```

Comment: Did you try without `RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]` rule in .htaccess?

Comment: Yes I have, but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the fix:

```
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '');
```

Needs to be changed to

```
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
```

To rewrite

```
http://domain.devwp-admin/network/settings.php
```

To

```
http://domain.dev/wp-admin/network/settings.php
```